# Remove Gradient and make Transparent navigation bar in ios 15

Tags: swift, gradient, transparent, navigationbar, ios15

I have tried the following code to remove the gradient from navigation and make a transparent navigation bar for ios 15, But it didn't work on the same whereas in the lower version it works perfectly fine.

```
if let bar =  self.navigationController?.navigationBar {
            if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
                let navigationBarAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
                navigationBarAppearance.configureWithTransparentBackground()
                navigationBarAppearance.shadowImage = UIImage()
                self.title = ""
                navigationBarAppearance.backgroundImage = UIImage()
                navigationBarAppearance.backgroundColor = .clear
                UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = true
                UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = navigationBarAppearance
                UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = navigationBarAppearance   
        
            } else {
                bar.setBackgroundImage(FCUtil.getImageWithColor(color: UIColor.clear, size: bar.frame.size), for: UIBarMetrics.default)
                bar.isTranslucent = true
                bar.shadowImage = UIImage()
                self.title = ""
            }
        }
```

Please suggest to me, If I had missed something.

Comment: Please refer - https://nemecek.be/blog/126/how-to-disable-automatic-transparent-navbar-in-ios-15, maybe it is useful.

Answer (score 1):

The only problem with your code is the timing. You are running the code too late. Changing the navigation bar `appearance()` cannot change a navigation bar that already exists.

Instead, just change `bar` itself, directly:

```
bar.standardAppearance = navigationBarAppearance
bar.scrollEdgeAppearance = navigationBarAppearance
```